# GitHub Actions workflow cancelling a step on itself

Tags: github, github-actions, python-poetry

Below is the step:

```yaml
- name: run
  if: endsWith(github.ref, '/feature')
  run: |
    echo "installing dependencies"
    pip3 install --upgrade pip
    pip3 install poetry
    cd job-extract/trans/project-v2
    poetry install
    echo "executing dbt"
    make source_dbt
    make run_catalog_server
    make run_scheduled_refresh
```

I am putting the logs which indicate that GitHub Actions workflow is cancelling the step itself. Please let me know how this can be resolved.

Also please let me know how can I use a notify action to catch and notify such runs?

Logs: [logslink](https://pastebin.com/FLqQTNSN)

Comment: Please include the error logs as text in your question. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [status check functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions) with `if` e.g. `always()` to execute a step no matter what. In that you can send a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use 'concurrency' in your workflow?

> can i use a notify action to catch and notify such runs?

Yes, you can try something like this (and replace 'echo' with some Slack action):

```
notification-job:
  needs: build-job
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  if: cancelled()
  steps:
    - name: Notification
      run: echo "i was canceled "
```

Comment: The attached workflow is invalid. Its YAML formatting needs to be fixed.